# Pointer points on wrong element in linked list (C)

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'd like to implement a liked list in my program:
The first two elements are inserted correctly but then the next elements start pointing on themselves: (as you can see in my output)

```
0
(nil)
1
0x7fffb3899340
(nil)
2
0x7fffb3899350
0x7fffb3899350
3
0x7fffb3899350
0x7fffb3899350
```

This is my method which should return a pointer to the first element:

```
Filediff* compare(File f1, File f2){
    int line = 0;
    Filediff *first = &(Filediff){line, 0, NULL}; //First elem
    char c1,
         c2;

    printf("w1\n");
    while ((c1 = fgetc(f1.content)) != EOF && (c2 = fgetc(f2.content)) != EOF)
    {
        if(c1 == '\n' || c2 == '\n'){
            line++;
            printf("%p\n", first->next);
                if(line >= 2)
                    printf("%p\n", first->next->next);
            first = &(Filediff){line, 0, first}; //insert last elem in new record.
        }else if(c1 != c2)
            first->charCount++;
        printf("%c %c\n", c1, c2);
    }

    fclose(f1.content);
    fclose(f2.content);

    return first;
}
```

One record of my list looks like this:

```
typedef struct Filediff
{
    int line;
    int charCount;
    struct Filediff *next;
} Filediff;
```

Thanks for helping me out with this!

Comment: first is on the stack! You need to allocate and free your memory

Comment: That's what I was thinking at first. I'm not that tallented in C programming. Is this the right way? (in my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way of implementing a linked list in my Case.

```
Filediff* compare(File f1, File f2){
int line = 0;
Filediff *first;
first = (Filediff*)malloc(sizeof *first);
first->line = line;
first->charCount = 0;
first->next = NULL;
char c1,
     c2;

while ((c1 = fgetc(f1.content)) != EOF && (c2 = fgetc(f2.content)) != EOF)
{
    if(c1 == '\n' || c2 == '\n'){
        printf("%d\n", line);
        line++;
        printf("%p\n", first->next);
            if(line >= 2)
                printf("%p\n", first->next->next);
        Filediff *buf = (Filediff*)malloc(sizeof *first);
        buf->line = line;
        buf->charCount = 0;
        buf->next = first;
        first = buf;
        //first = &(Filediff){line, 0, first};
    }else if(c1 != c2)
        first->charCount++;
}

    fclose(f1.content);
    fclose(f2.content);

    return first;
}
```

Comment: Your last node in the list will still be on the stack. I think you don't need the dummy node and you can just initialize `Filediff *first = NULL;`.

Comment: The dummy node is my first elem. I would get an error when I do 'first->charCount++;'

Comment: I see; it is your first line. But you should also allocate that on the heap with `malloc`. (It may seem that it works, but your head node is created on the stack and will be illegal on returning from the function.)

Comment: Ok thank you. Is it possible to create my linked list without malloc?

Comment: You can create your list in an array, where the `next` pointers point into other entries of that array. Everything will be like a linked list, except that you can't overflow the array, i.e. your list can only have a certain maximum number of nodes. If you don't need the linked list advantages (like easy insertion and removal of nodes) you might be better off using an array anyway.

Comment: Thx for explaining. the linked list is exactly what I want.